# Flexbox unable to move content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm currently working on a project for school where I have to redesign another student's website using only CSS. I've been trying to implement flexbox, but whenever I give a class any of the flex properties, nothing really happens. I had to set the body as the flex container as there was no other option. I've tried setting a few different things and got a li to work but that is it. The albums and albums1 classes are barely responding at this point.

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: url(img/back.png);
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: Ubuntu, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #8AE5D8;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  list-style: none;
}

li a {
  margin: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #000;
  font-family: Ubuntu, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.background {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.albums,
.albums1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#about" title="about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#ablums" title="ablums">Albums</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contactus" title="contactus">Contact Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tours" title="tours">Tours</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
<h6 id="ablums"></h6>
<img class="background" src="img/background-image.jpg" alt="background">
<h2 class="albums1">Eclipse</h2>
<div class="albums">
  <img src="img/journey_eclipse-tn.jpg" alt="Ecli" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text"></div>
    <ol>
      <li>City of Hope</li>
      <li>Edge of the Moment</li>
      <li>Chain of Love</li>
      <li>Tantra (My Eyes Can See)</li>
      <li>Anything is Possible</li>
      <li>Resonate</li>
      <li>She's a Mystery</li>
      <li>Human Feel</li>
      <li>Ritual</li>
      <li>To Whom It May Concern</li>
      <li>Someone</li>
      <li>Venus</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
```

Comment: The things your putting the `album` classes on aren't doing anything because they don't have any children or even text in it. For example `<h6>`, `<h2>` you're trying to align items in it, instead of using `align-self` or otherwise. This site is a good use for visualizing how flexbox works : http://flexboxfroggy.com/ and here is a great resource for documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox and lastly here is a great tutorial: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: The id ablums is what I think you may be looking at. As far as the albums go they are given the classes albums and albums1. albums had a ol child element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not totally sure what you are after, and the code you provided doesn't clear things up much either.  I second the suggestion in the comments to checkout flexboxfroggy as a fun and simple exercise to learn about the basics of Flexbox.

At any rate, below is one suggestion of how you might format your layout.  I stripped your markup down a bit to remove any images/overlays since you didn't provide much info as to what you're hoping to achieve. It's probably best to focus on the basics of Flexbox layout, and understand first and foremost that applying `display: flex` to a container will only effect the children inside the container you are applying it to.  The descendants of a flex item are formatted independently, regardless of the flex container.  It can get a little tricky when you have multiple nested flex containers and need to change the `flex-direction` as needed.

Anyways, hope this example might help you out a bit.  [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/37xwwq7d/1/) is a fiddle as well.

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: black;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: Ubuntu, Arial, sans-serif;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
}

li a {
  margin: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #000;
  font-family: Ubuntu, Arial, sans- serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

ol  {
 padding: 0;   
}

ol li  {
 list-style-position: inside;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding-right: 5%;
  background-color: #8AE5D8;
}

.albums-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.albums {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 5%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: slategrey;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#about" title="about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#ablums" title="ablums">Albums</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contactus" title="contactus">Contact Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tours" title="tours">Tours</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="albums-container">
  <div class="albums">
    <ol>
      <h2 class="albums1">Eclipse</h2>
      <li>City of Hope</li>
      <li>Edge of the Moment</li>
      <li>Chain of Love</li>
      <li>Tantra (My Eyes Can See)</li>
      <li>Anything is Possible</li>
      <li>Resonate</li>
      <li>She's a Mystery</li>
      <li>Human Feel</li>
      <li>Ritual</li>
      <li>To Whom It May Concern</li>
      <li>Someone</li>
      <li>Venus</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <div class="albums">
    <ol>
      <h2 class="albums1">Eclipse</h2>
      <li>City of Hope</li>
      <li>Edge of the Moment</li>
      <li>Chain of Love</li>
      <li>Tantra (My Eyes Can See)</li>
      <li>Anything is Possible</li>
      <li>Resonate</li>
      <li>She's a Mystery</li>
      <li>Human Feel</li>
      <li>Ritual</li>
      <li>To Whom It May Concern</li>
      <li>Someone</li>
      <li>Venus</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <div class="albums">
    <ol>
      <h2 class="albums1">Eclipse</h2>
      <li>City of Hope</li>
      <li>Edge of the Moment</li>
      <li>Chain of Love</li>
      <li>Tantra (My Eyes Can See)</li>
      <li>Anything is Possible</li>
      <li>Resonate</li>
      <li>She's a Mystery</li>
      <li>Human Feel</li>
      <li>Ritual</li>
      <li>To Whom It May Concern</li>
      <li>Someone</li>
      <li>Venus</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I realize now that I forgot to put what I was wanting to do. Sorry about that. Essentially the movement like what you had in the fiddle is what I am trying to achieve but I am not allowed to make any sort of changes to the HTML at all. Everything must be done in CSS. Thank you for clearing up the flexbox thing though. I think I may have figured it out.